# Multilevel unordered list into interactive horizontal menus

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a nested unordered list. I need to display this as horizontal menus below each other. The biggest problem is I don't know in how many levels I will get in this list, so I want to create functionality that will work for n-level list depth.

Example of list:

```
<ul id="data">
    <li>
        <h1>Menu 1</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>Menu 1-1</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>Some content A</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Menu 1-2</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>Some content B</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Menu 2</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>Menu 2-1</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>Some content C</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Menu 2-2</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>Some content E</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The idea how this will work is:

```
Menu 1    Menu 2  
Menu 1-1    Menu 1-2
```

Other lists are hidden by default. When I click on Menu 2 the result must be:

```
Menu 1    Menu 2
Menu 2-1    Menu 2-2
```

When I click on a specific `<h1>`, and the `<ul>` element in the same level as this element has no children `<h1>`, element `<div>` is displayed below the menus. In our case: when I click on Menu 1-1 div with content 'Some content A' is displayed.

I have tried with recursion and with just using CSS but I can't get it to work. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the jQuery code you need is:

```
$(function(){
    $('h1').click(function(){
        var parentUl = $(this).closest('ul');
        if (parentUl.hasClass('active')) {
            var sibsWithActive = parentUl.find('ul.active');
            if (sibsWithActive) {
                sibsWithActive.removeClass('active');
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            $('ul.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle doc that demonstrates it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nLgVt/

Obviously the css is ver rudimentary.

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I needed. Is it possible to align sub menu of Menu 2 to the left?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I can't quite, get my head around it at the moment but I'd use some positioning on the child elements. Possibly it might need to be absolute but then you'd need to set widths etc.

Comment: I added this to css left: 0; to ul li ul.active and it worked. Thnx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/sxDbu/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <ul id="data">
    <li><h1>Menu 1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><h1>Menu 1-1</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Some content A</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><h1>Menu 1-2</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><h1>Menu 1-2-1</h1>
              <ul>
                <li><h1>Menu 1-2-1-1</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><div>Some content A</div></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><h1>Menu 1-2-1-2</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><div>Some content B</div></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><h1>Menu 2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><h1>Menu 2-1</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Some content C</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><h1>Menu 2-2</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Some content D</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><h1>Menu 2-3</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Some content D</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active > h1 {
  background: #171717;
  color: #fff;
}

li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  "use strict";

  $('#outer-wrapper').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
  });
});
```